# Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found

Tags: java, regex, string

I think this is an easy question, but I am not able to find a simple solution (say, less than 10 lines of code :)

I have a `String` such as `"thisIsMyString"` and I need to convert it to a `String[] {"this", "Is", "My", "String"}`.

Please notice the first letter is not uppercase.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You may use a regexp with zero-width positive lookahead - it finds uppercase letters but doesn't include them into delimiter:

```
String s = "thisIsMyString";
String[] r = s.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
```

`Y(?=X)` matches `Y` followed by `X`, but doesn't include `X` into match. So `(?=\\p{Upper})` matches an empty sequence followed by a uppercase letter, and `split` uses it as a delimiter.

See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more info on Java regexp syntax.

**EDIT:** By the way, it doesn't work with `thisIsMyÜberString`. For non-ASCII uppercase letters you need a Unicode uppercase character class instead of POSIX one:

```
String[] r = s.split("(?=\\p{Lu})");
```

Comment: +1, you were first (by a few seconds), + explanation, + the predefined upper class :)

Comment: Just be aware that if the upper character is the last in the string that you won't receive an empty str for the bit beyond it, e.g. splitting "H2W" will return { "", "2" } where "" is the bit before "H", and "2" is the bit in the middle. Normally not an issue but it can break assumptions about how many parts are returned.

Comment: @locka: Is there a way around that, other than explicitly checking?

Comment: Perhaps you could append your own string on the end as a sacrificial throwaway, e.g. append "Xblah" to your string, then just treat the last "blah" in your array as an empty string. It wouldn't hurt to run your matcher through unit tests with various string values to make sure you get the behaviour you expect.

Comment: for **Kotlin**  `s.split(Regex("(?=\\p{Upper})"))`

Answer (score 27):

```
String[] camelCaseWords = s.split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

Comment: axtavt already gave a correct answer to Guido's question, so why answer twice? Your answer is wrong, so I downvoted it and pointed out why.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone that wonders how the Pattern is when the String to split might start with an upper case character:

```java
String s = "ThisIsMyString";
String[] r = s.split("(?<=.)(?=\\p{Lu})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
```

gives: [This, Is, My, String]

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the addition !

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Since `String::split` takes a regular expression you can use a look-ahead:

```
String[] x = "thisIsMyString".split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\\p{Lu})");
String[] s1 = p.split("thisIsMyFirstString");
String[] s2 = p.split("thisIsMySecondString");

...
```

Comment: I tried every answer here and this was the only one that worked for me. Plus it makes a lot of sense to just compile the pattern once. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will split on Caps, omitting the first.  So it should work for camel-case and proper-case.

```
(?<=.)(?=(\\p{Upper}))

TestText = Test, Text
thisIsATest = this, Is, A, Test
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple scala/java suggestion that does not split at entire uppercase strings like *NYC*:

```scala
def splitAtMiddleUppercase(token: String): Iterator[String] = {
   val regex = """[\p{Lu}]*[^\p{Lu}]*""".r
   regex.findAllIn(token).filter(_ != "") // did not find a way not to produce empty strings in the regex. Open to suggestions.
}
```

test with:

```scala
val examples = List("catch22", "iPhone", "eReplacement", "TotalRecall", "NYC", "JGHSD87", "interÜber")
for( example <- examples) {
   println(example + " -> "  + splitAtMiddleUppercase(example).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
}
```

it produces:

```
    catch22 -> [catch22]
    iPhone -> [i, Phone]
    eReplacement -> [e, Replacement]
    TotalRecall -> [Total, Recall]
    NYC -> [NYC]
    JGHSD87 -> [JGHSD87]
    interÜber -> [inter, Über]
```

Modify the regex to cut at digits too.

Answer (score -1):

```
      String str = "IAmAJavaProgrammer";
  StringBuilder expected = new StringBuilder(); 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){    
            expected.append(" ");
        }
        expected.append(str.charAt(i));


}

System.out.println(expected);
```

Comment: Plz read question carefully, it need to convert arrays of string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).