# Split by capital letters in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a string by capitals and preferably make subsequent words lower case;

for example

ThisIsAString becomes This is a string

Thanks

Comment: have you copied question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found

Comment: "give me teh codez" gets an up-vote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate of anything thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to convert camelcase into readable language.  Is that the case?

If so, this solution should work for you - [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

If you want subsequent words lowercased, you'll have to split to handle that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a string you can do so:

```
String str = "ThisIsAString";
String res = "";
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   Character ch = str.charAt(i);
     if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
       res += " " + Character.toLowerCase(ch);
     else
       res += ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String cpt(String cpt){
    String new_string = "";
    for (int i=0; i < cpt.length(); i++){
        char c = cpt.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){               
            new_string = new_string + " " + Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        else {
            new_string = new_string + c;
        }
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Total Number of Words in a Camel Case word using char casing identification**

Solution: to Hacker Rank camel case problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/camelcase/problem

```
public static void camelCaseWordWithIndexs(String s) {


    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) || i == s.length() - 1) {
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = i != s.length() - 1 ? i : i + 1;
            System.out.println(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
        }
    }


}
```