# split based on uppercase in java

Tags: java, uppercase

Anyone know how to do how to covert `FirstName` to `First Name`.

The splitting has to take place based on The **Upper-Case** letters , but it should exclude the first letter.

I know how to do it using split.
There is any other way to do it apart from split functionality.

Comment: what is your code for `split`?

Comment: You can find a the answer to your question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found

Answer (score 5):

Not really `split`, just `replaceAll`:

```
str.replaceAll("(?!^)([A-Z])", " $1")
```

This solution assumes that you don't want to add space before an uppercase English alphabet if it is the first character in the string. So, `" FirstName"` will become `"  First Name"` (note the 2 spaces).

`(?!^)` is negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)`, just checking this is not the beginning of the string `^`. I capture `(pattern)` the uppercase English alphabet, and use the captured text in the replacement `$1` (`$1` means whatever captured in capturing group **1** is put in the replacement string - in this case there is only 1 capturing group).

Another solution that add space before an uppercase English alphabet, only if it is preceded by lowercase English alphabet:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1")
```

`(?<=[a-z])` is a positive look-behind `(?<=pattern)` that checks whether the capital characters `[A-Z]` is preceded by lowercase English alphabet `[a-z]`. The rest has been explained above.

The pattern can vary a lot based on the requirement. You only give one example instead of concrete requirement, so I will take a wild guess and pick out a pattern for you.

Comment: m really bad with regex so editing answer with explanation would be lot more expressive (including that `" $1"` part

Answer (score 4):

6 to 11 times faster than replaceAll :

```
  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder( "FirstName" );
  for( int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i ) {
     if( Character.isUpperCase( s.charAt( i ))) {
        s.insert( i++, ' ' );
     }
  }
```

bench :

```
  long atStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for( int j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j ) {
     StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder( "FirstName" );
     for( int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i ) {
        if( Character.isUpperCase( s.charAt( i ))) {
           s.insert( i++, ' ' );
        }
     }
  }
  long elapsed1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - atStart;

  atStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for( int j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j ) {
     String s = "FirstName";
     s = s.replaceAll("(?!^)([A-Z])", " $1");
  }
  long elapsed2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - atStart;

  System.err.println( "Ratio: " + elapsed2 / (double)elapsed1 );
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html: As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snap

```
   String array[]= "FirstMiddleLast".replaceAll("(?!^)([A-Z])", " $1").split(" ");
   for(String name:array){
      System.out.println(name);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own, something like this:

```
private String split(String string) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Character character: string.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(character)) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(character);
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the use of the archaic StringBuffer, as StringBuilder is faster. Maybe that `for (i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) { char ch = string.charAt(i);` seems more efficient. I like the answer though.

Comment: @JoopEggen: StringBuffer is thread-safe (not really needed here, but well, it is not because it is archaic that we should not use), while StringBuilder is not.

Comment: @nhahtdh and Matcher uses StringBuffer for search-replace code. But as it is more inefficient, such that StringBuilder was introduced one should try to use StringBuilder whenever possible.

Comment: Can you at least provide an explanation of why/how your answer solves the problem?