# Adding curly braces between each text

Tags: java, split

Pretend I have a text of string:

```
String stuff = "Cat" + "Meow" + "Sit" + "Bark";
```

How do I add curly braces to each word?

```
Output: {Cat}{Meow}{Sit}{Bark}
```

I think I use split, but I don't fully understand the split method.

Comment: they way you are concatenating the words will give u thia word CatMeowSitBark therefore split won't be able to help you u need to add some separator in between like a whitespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the words have to be separated with some pattern, otherwise you won't be able to do it dynamically, let's say is

string words= word word word word word word (between each word there is an space, or whatever you want)

```
string [] wordArray=words.split(pattern you choose to separete the words)

string finalWords="";
for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
{
finalWords+="{"+wordArray[i]+"}";
}
```

then in the finalWords variable will be the desire result

Comment: This gives me an idea, thanks. I'll give it a try. EDIT: Actually nvm.

Comment: I think I'm too new to do that. I just gave you a green check.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stuff = "{" + "Cat" + "}" + "{" + "Meow" + "}" + "{" + "Sit" + "}" +  "{" + "Bark" + "}";
```

Comment: Isn't there a method without having to hard code all that?

Comment: @Evyione Can you give a little more information about where you're getting this string, why the values aren't separated by anything, and what you're trying to do overall?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a method for putting all the curly braces between the words. It's just a string I made up. My friend told me to do a for loop and just add the curly braces... Right now, I'm wondering on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

u need to add something as a separator to your string say a comma

```
 String stuff = "Cat:" + "Meow:" + "Sit:" + "Bark";
```

then you can split the string this way

```
 String[] parts = stuff.split(":")
```

Then you loop over the strings and add the curly braces

```
 stuff_with_curlyB = "" ; 
 for(i =0; i< parts.length; i++)
  {
      stuff_with_curlyB += "{"+parts[i]+"}";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like that:

```
public static String concatenateWithCurlyBraces(final String... strs) {
    final StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (final String str: strs)
        strBuilder.append('{').append(str).append('}');
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

And call it like that:

```
String stuff = concatenateWithCurlyBraces("Cat", "Meow", "Sit", "Bark");
```