# java regular expression: conditionally spilt string by capital letters

Tags: java, regex, string

I am not familiar with regular expression. Maybe this is a simple problem.
Given a string

```
XYZHelloWorldT
```

I need to return an string array as

```
{XYZ Hello World T}
```

That is, take all the words that start with exactly *one capital letter* and followed by *one or more small letters* or *multiple capital letters*, followed by *a capital letter* starting a new word. The remaining part is separated by the vacancies to be the other elements in the string array.

I can work on the characters directly. Just wonder whether I could do it by regular expression directly in string's split method? I found something like this [Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found) but not sure how to use it to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Do you have always this format of string?

Comment: It could be "HelloWorld" or "XYZHelloWorld". I am not sure how to separate XYZ from Hello? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can have multiple consecutive upper case letters, you want to have lookbehind for lower case as well as lookahead for upper case:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

If you want support for other languages, you should use [posix character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

```
(?<=\\p{Lower})(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\p{Upper})(?=\\p{Upper}\\p{Lower})
```

---

The first alternation will match if you are between lowercase and uppercase letters. The second one - if you are between an upper case and another upper case, followed by lower case.

Comment: That returns [XYZHello, World, T]. How to split XYZ from Hello

Answer (score 0):

This is algorithm in Java for find this words, but only not recommend for big texts, also not includes numbers and whitespace.

```js
public class TestString
{
 static int i = 0, lenght;
 static char array[];
 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String result = "XYZHelloWorldTRTTTePoPoIiiiiiooY";
  array = result.toCharArray();
  lenght=array.length;

  StringBuffer words = new StringBuffer();
  for(; i< lenght; i++){
   words.append(makeArray());
  }
  String resultOut[]= words.toString().split(",");
  for(String key: resultOut){
   System.out.println(key);
  }
  System.exit(0);
 }

 private static String makeArray()
 {
  StringBuffer word = new StringBuffer();
  String upper, normal;
  boolean lower=false;
  for(; i< lenght; ++i){
   word.append(array[i]);
   if(i<lenght-2){
    upper=String.valueOf(array[i+1]).toUpperCase();
    normal=String.valueOf(array[i+1]);
    if(upper.equals(normal)){
     upper=String.valueOf(array[i+2]).toUpperCase();
     normal=String.valueOf(array[i+2]);
     if(upper.equals(normal)){
      if(lower){
       break;
      }
      continue;
      
     }else{
      break;
     }
    }else{
     lower=true;
     continue;
    }
   }else{
    if(lower && i<lenght-1){
     String lowerStr=String.valueOf(array[i+1]).toLowerCase();
     normal=String.valueOf(array[i+1]);
     if(lowerStr.equals(normal)){
      continue;
     }else{
      break;
      
     }
    }
    break;
   }
  }
  word.append(",");
  return word.toString();
 }
}
```

> what's your plan to use this regex in my algorithm?