# How to list all words matching criteria from String sentence in Java

Tags: java, string

Imagine having following 'sentence' as String object:

```
String sentence = "AsomethingB 123 AsomethingElseB AsomethingBC abc A0B 987 ...";
```

How can I list everything to a `String[]` of words which begins with String `A` and ends with String `B`, like:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"AsomethingB", "AsomethingElseB", "A0B"};
// note the AsomethingBC is not here.
```

More globally I am looking for method which will do following:

```
public String[] listWords(String sentence, String startSequence, String endSequence) {
  // sentence will represent String from which "extract" words
  // startSequence will represent "A" from example, may contain more characters
  // endSequence will represent "B" from example, may contain more characters
  // return type String[] will return all matches (AsomethingB...) from example
    }
```

Is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java 8's streams to get the result, e.g.:

```
public static String[] listWords(String sentence, String startSequence, String endSequence) {
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith(startSequence))
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith(endSequence))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

This method splits the spring based on space and performs the comparison. You can call this method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listWords("AsomethingB 123 AsomethingElseB AsomethingBC abc A0B 987", "A", "B")));  
}
```

You can also use `toLowerCase()` method if you want case insensitive matching.

**Update**

If you words are not split by whitespace and you want to `split` on capital letters then you can use the following (assuming the string will contain numbers as well):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("AsomethingB123AsomethingElseBAsomethingBCabcA0B987".split("(?=[A-Z])(?<=[A-Z])|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")));
```

This would show the tokens that are applied to the stream.

Also, on a second thought, it'll be better to add one more parameter (`regex`) to `listWords` method so that it's not tied to any specific pattern, e.g.:

```
public static String[] listWords(String sentence, String regex, String startSequence, String endSequence) {
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(regex))
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith(startSequence))
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith(endSequence))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listWords("AsomethingB123AsomethingElseBAsomethingBCabcA0B987", "(?=[A-Z])(?<=[A-Z])|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", "A", "B")));
```

Comment: Thanks great answer! But what if these words are not splitted by whitespace ?  For example : `AsomethingB123AsomethingElseBAsomethingBCabcA0B987`

Comment: If you want to split by uppercase letter then you can just use `(? =\\p{Upper})` inside the `split` method. Have a look at this SO answer for splitting a string with Upper case letter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found

Comment: `split` accepts a `regex`, so you can specify any pattern and it will spit the string by that pattern. Here is the javadoc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Don't bother first collecting the stream to a list, then converting the list to an array. Replace .collect(...).toArray... directly with .toArray(size -> new String[size])

Comment: EDIT: Any idea what I am doing wrong if the Uppercase regex returns nothing ?

Comment: @user889742 thanks for the input, really appreciated. Csb Xo, could you provide an example?

Comment: Tried your method with parameters ( "AsomethingB123AsomethingElseBAsomethingBCabcA0B987 ", "A", "B" ) with pattern .split("(? =\\p{Upper})")

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
return Pattern.compile(" ")
        .splitAsStream(sentence)
        .filter(w -> w.startsWith(startSequence))
        .filter(w -> w.endsWith(endSequence))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-streams approach:

```
public static List<String> listWords(String sentence, String startSequence, String endSequence) {
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : sentence.split(" "))
        if (s.startsWith(startSequence) && s.endsWith(endSequence))
            lst.add(s);
    return lst;
}
```

Done it as a `List<String>` because they're less faff than arrays.  You can always convert it afterwards if you really need an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the Java's .split command. So it could like like:

```
String sentence = "My Sentence AbbC";
String[] splitted = sentence.split(" ");
```

and then from there you can loop over the splitted array to find if your index has the desired result. Furthermore, you can also try .split("A*B") which would result in splitted containing strings that start and end with A and B respectively as being in their own singular index, while everything else would be as one long string in an index.

ex:

S: AbbD
S:  Hello World, Acc