# How to split Strings in java

Tags: java, string

I have two types of Strings. One is `"abcdEfgh"` and `"abcd efgh"`. That means first String is having upper case letter in between and second string is having white space. So now how do I check these two pattern string in java and make two strings.

```
String givenString;

if (givenString.equals("abcdEfgh")) {
   String str1 = abcd;
   String str2 = Efgh;
} else (givenString.equals("abcd efgh") {
   String str1 = abcd;
   String str2 = efgh;
}
```

Please provide the solution
Thanks

Comment: String class has a split method. `givenString.split(" ");` for the white space example.

Comment: And for the uppercase example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, as the question is about both cases (capital or white space delimiter), not one of them.

Comment: Could it be mixed "abcdEfgh rest"? Are there always extactly two parts to find?

Answer (score 5):

You can split using regex `\\s|(?=[A-Z])`

1. `\\s` is to deal with case of whitespace.
2. `(?=[A-Z])`is positive lookahead. It finds capital letter but keeps the delimiter while splitting.

.

```
String givenString;
String split[] = givenString.split("\\s|(?=[A-Z])");
String str1 = split[0];
String str2 = split[1];
```

---

for both cases

Test case 1

```
//case 1
givenString = "abcdEfgh";
str1 = abcd
str2 = Efgh
```

Test case 2

```
//case 2
givenString = "abcd efgh";
str1 = abcd
str2 = efgh
```

Comment: @RamanSahasi Thanks for your ans. I am getting , str1=null and str2=abcd in the Test case 1

Comment: @PratibhaPatil I've compiled and tested this code. Please take a look at [this online version of my test cases](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWGdEbkJERm12dUU).

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the two conditions using the OR operator `|`. You've already figured out split by space is simply " ". The uppercase example is answered by [Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found)

Example

```
String one = "abcdEfgh";
String two = "abcd efgh";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one.split(" |(?=\\p{Upper})")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two.split(" |(?=\\p{Upper})")));
```

Output

```
[abcd, Efgh]
[abcd, efgh]
```

Comment: Thanks@Adam, both for upper case and white space same pattern ?

Comment: @PratibhaPatil Yep, as my example shows the same pattern can be used

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, search for space in **givenString** instead of case sensitive matchs

```
if(givenString.indexOf(" ") != -1){
    System.out.println( "The string has spaces");
}else{
    System.out.println( "The string has NO spaces");
}
```