# java: How do I split a string on space and uppercase letter?

Tags: java, string, split

For an example: `"Today's food will be fish Tomorrow's food will be soup"`

I want a string array that contains

```
{Today's food will be fish,Tomorrow's food will be soup}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Split string when an uppercase letter is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found)

Comment: @billynomates no. I want to split the string if the the index before the uppercase letter is "" or " ".

Comment: @SubOptimal mystring.split("/(?<=[.?!]\\s)(?=[A-Z])/")

Comment: you can include what you tried in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use split with this regex `(?=\s[A-Z])` for example :

```
String str = "Today's food will be fish Tomorrow's food will be soup";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("(?=\\s[A-Z])")));
```

Outputs

```
[Today's food will be fish,  Tomorrow's food will be soup]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String a="Today's food will be fish Tomorrow's food will be soup";
String[] b = a.split("\\s(?=[A-Z])");
```

and b is : [Today's food will be fish, Tomorrow's food will be soup]

Answer (score 0):

To support international characters I'd recommend the following expression, building on YCF_L:s answer.

```
String str = "Today's food will be fish Tomorrow's food will be soup";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("(?=\\s\\p{Lu})")));
```