# Use regex to un camelCase Java String

Tags: java, regex, string

This code seems to work perfectly, but I'd love to clean it up with regex.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "IAmASentenceInCamelCaseWithNumbers500And1And37";
    System.out.println(unCamelCase(s));
}

public static String unCamelCase(String string) {
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(string.length() * 2);
    newString.append(string.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(string.charAt(i)) && string.charAt(i - 1) != ' '
            || Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i - 1))) {
            newString.append(' ');
        }
        newString.append(string.charAt(i));
    }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Input:

```
IAmASentenceInCamelCaseWithNumbers500And1And37
```

Output:

```
I Am A Sentence In Camel Case With Numbers 500 And 1 And 37
```

I'm not a fan of using  that ugly if statement, and I'm hoping there's a way to use a single line of code that utilizes regex. I tried for a bit but it would fail on words with 1 or 2 letters.

Failing code that doesn't work:

```
return string.replaceAll("(.)([A-Z0-9]\\w)", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found   
You can also use Apache commons StringUtils's splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase() method:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right regex and code to do your job is this.

```
String s = "IAmASentenceInCamelCaseWithNumbers500And1And37";
System.out.println("Output: " + s.replaceAll("[A-Z]|\\d+", " $0").trim());
```

This outputs,

```
Output: I Am A Sentence In Camel Case With Numbers 500 And 1 And 37
```

**Editing answer for query asked by OP in comment:**

If input string is,

```
ThisIsAnABBRFor1Abbreviation
```

Regex needs a little modification and becomes this, `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]|\\d+` for handling abbreviation.

This code,

```
String s = "ThisIsAnABBRFor1Abbreviation";
System.out.println("Input: " + s.replaceAll("[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]|\\d+", " $0").trim());
```

Gives expected output as per OP ZeekAran in comment,

```
Input: This Is An ABBR For 1 Abbreviation
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. Is there any simple way to add abbreviation support as well? IE, input: "ThisIsAnABBRFor1Abbreviation" and output: "This Is An ABBR for 1 Abbreviation"

Comment: This is (slightly) different from what the unCamelCase function in the question. This approach may introduce double spaces, if the original input already contains spaces. I.e. the `string.charAt(i - 1) != ' '`condition is not taken into account by this regex replacement.

Comment: @ZeekAran: Yes regex will need a little modification. Edited my answer for your case in comment.

Comment: @Alderath: That is true, but for my case, I think my IDE will let me know my function name is invalid first.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can try this**

```js
let str = "IAmASentenceInCamelCaseWithNumbers500And1And37";

function unCamelCase(str){
  return str.replace(/(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]+)/g, (m)=>' '+m.toUpperCase()).trim();
}

console.log(unCamelCase(str));
```

> Explanation

```
(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]+)
```

`?:`  - Non capturing group.

`[A-Z]` - Matches any one capital character.

'|' - Alternation (This works same as Logical OR).

`[0-9]+` - Matches any digit from 0-9 one or more time.

**P.S** Sorry for the example in JavaScript but same logic can be achived in JAVA pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this lookaround based regex solution:

```
final String result = string.replaceAll(
   "(?<=\\S)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[^\\s\\d])(?=\\d)", " ");

//=> I Am A Sentence In Camel Case With Numbers 500 And 1 And 37
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNZDje/1)

**RegEx Details:**

Regex matches either of 2 conditions and replaces it with a space. It will ignore already present spaces in input.

- `(?<=\\S)(?=[A-Z])`: Previous char is non-space and next char is a uppercase letter
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=[^\\s\\d])(?=\\d)`: previous char is non-digit & non-space and next one is a digit